# High CPU Usage on Juno in Chrome during video playback

Tags: release-juno, google-chrome, chromebook

First and foremost thanks for the awesome work that has been done with elementary os - it truly is a work of art and I've donated to the project to show my support.
I was able to successfully install juno on my chromebook, a samsung chromebook pro. It has an intel M3 processor and with its HIDPI display elementary looks amazing. The only issue I have is when I stream movies via plex or netflix the CPU usage in chrome or firefox goes through the roof. It jumps up to somewhere around 120-130% and the laptop gets physically hot. I've tried different kernels (installed via ukuu) from 4.16 all the way up to 4.19 and nothing seems to have helped. Any tips or other things I could try? I'd really love to get elementary dialed in on this machine. Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately even with this flag set I am still seeing about 130-180% cpu usage during video playback. Here is a copy of what my chrome://gpu report looks like:

`Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Flash: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Hardware accelerated
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
Native GpuMemoryBuffers: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Out-of-process Rasterization: Disabled
Hardware Protected Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Skia Deferred Display List: Disabled
Skia Renderer: Disabled
Surface Synchronization: Enabled
Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
Viz Service Display Compositor: Disabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
Driver Bug Workarounds
adjust_src_dst_region_for_blitframebuffer
clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
count_all_in_varyings_packing
decode_encode_srgb_for_generatemipmap
disable_framebuffer_cmaa
disable_post_sub_buffers_for_onscreen_surfaces
msaa_is_slow
scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args
disabled_extension_GL_ARB_timer_query
disabled_extension_GL_EXT_timer_query
disabled_extension_GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
disabled_extension_GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
Problems Detected
Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: 124764, 349137
Applied Workarounds: clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
Mesa drivers in Linux handle varyings without static use incorrectly: 333885
Applied Workarounds: count_all_in_varyings_packing
Disable partial swaps on Mesa drivers (detected with GL_RENDERER): 339493
Applied Workarounds: disable_post_sub_buffers_for_onscreen_surfaces
Always rewrite vec/mat constructors to be consistent: 398694
Applied Workarounds: scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args
On Intel GPUs MSAA performance is not acceptable for GPU rasterization: 527565
Applied Workarounds: msaa_is_slow
Timer queries crash on Intel GPUs on Linux: 540543, 576991
Applied Workarounds: disable(GL_ARB_timer_query), disable(GL_EXT_timer_query)
Use GL_INTEL_framebuffer_CMAA on ChromeOS: 535198
Applied Workarounds: disable_framebuffer_cmaa
Disable partial swaps on Mesa drivers (detected with GL_VERSION): 339493
Applied Workarounds: disable_post_sub_buffers_for_onscreen_surfaces
Decode and encode before generateMipmap for srgb format textures on os except macosx: 634519
Applied Workarounds: decode_encode_srgb_for_generatemipmap
adjust src/dst region if blitting pixels outside read framebuffer on Linux Intel: 664740
Applied Workarounds: adjust_src_dst_region_for_blitframebuffer
Disable KHR_blend_equation_advanced until cc shaders are updated: 661715
Applied Workarounds: disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced), disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent)
Native GpuMemoryBuffers have been disabled, either via about:flags or command line.
Disabled Features: native_gpu_memory_buffers
Viz service display compositor is not enabled by default.
Disabled Features: viz_display_compositor
Skia renderer is not used by default.
Disabled Features: skia_renderer
Skia deferred display list is not used by default.
Disabled Features: skia_deferred_display_list
Version Information
Data exported   2018-11-07T15:28:46.500Z
Chrome version  Chrome/70.0.3538.77
Operating system    Linux 4.15.0-38-generic
Software rendering list URL https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/0f6ce0b0cd63a12cb4eccea3637b1bc9a29148d9/gpu/config/software_rendering_list.json
Driver bug list URL https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/0f6ce0b0cd63a12cb4eccea3637b1bc9a29148d9/gpu/config/gpu_driver_bug_list.json
ANGLE commit id 05c729f336ef
2D graphics backend Skia/70 193565807f7fd2a2c14e21b44c545cc03ebe134f-
Command Line    /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --flag-switches-begin --ignore-gpu-blacklist --flag-switches-end
Driver Information
Initialization time 47
In-process GPU  false
Passthrough Command Decoder false
Sandboxed   true
GPU0    VENDOR = 0x8086 [Intel Open Source Technology Center], DEVICE= 0x191e [Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 515 (Skylake GT2) ] *ACTIVE*
Optimus false
AMD switchable  false
Driver vendor   Mesa
Driver version  18.0.5
Driver date 
GPU CUDA compute capability major version   0
Pixel shader version    1.30
Vertex shader version   1.30
Max. MSAA samples   16
Machine model name

Machine model version

GL_VENDOR   Intel Open Source Technology Center
GL_RENDERER Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 515 (Skylake GT2)
GL_VERSION  3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
GL_EXTENSIONS   GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_AMD_conservative_depth GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_APPLE_object_purgeable GL_APPLE_packed_pixels GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays GL_ARB_blend_func_extended GL_ARB_buffer_storage GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_clear_texture GL_ARB_clip_control GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_compute_shader GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted GL_ARB_conservative_depth GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_copy_image GL_ARB_cull_distance GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_derivative_control GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_internalformat_query2 GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_multi_bind GL_ARB_multisample GL_ARB_multitexture GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_polygon_offset_clamp GL_ARB_program_interface_query GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_query_buffer_object GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_sample_shading GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters GL_ARB_shader_ballot GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ARB_shader_clock GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters GL_ARB_shader_group_vote GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store GL_ARB_shader_image_size GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_precision GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_stencil_texturing GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_texture_barrier GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_gather GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_texture_multisample GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_texture_query_levels GL_ARB_texture_query_lod GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_texture_stencil8 GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_texture_view GL_ARB_timer_query GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_ARB_window_pos GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_ATI_draw_buffers GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3 GL_ATI_texture_float GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_copy_texture GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_point_parameters GL_EXT_polygon_offset GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_EXT_subtexture GL_EXT_texture GL_EXT_texture3D GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_cube_map GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3 GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_EXT_texture_object GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_timer_query GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_EXT_vertex_array GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_INGR_blend_func_separate GL_INTEL_performance_query GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_no_error GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_KHR_robustness GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba GL_MESA_window_pos GL_NV_blend_square GL_NV_conditional_render GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_NV_light_max_exponent GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_NV_texture_env_combine4 GL_NV_texture_rectangle GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_read_format GL_S3_s3tc GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays
Disabled Extensions GL_ARB_timer_query GL_EXT_timer_query GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
Disabled WebGL Extensions

Window system binding vendor    SGI
Window system binding version   1.4
Window system binding extensions    GLX_ARB_create_context GLX_ARB_create_context_profile GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_ARB_multisample GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_EXT_import_context GLX_EXT_libglvnd GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap GLX_EXT_visual_info GLX_EXT_visual_rating GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer GLX_OML_swap_method GLX_SGI_make_current_read GLX_SGI_swap_control GLX_SGIS_multisample GLX_SGIX_fbconfig GLX_SGIX_pbuffer GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group GLX_INTEL_swap_event
Window manager  Mutter(Gala)
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP Pantheon
GDMSESSION  pantheon
Compositing manager Yes
Direct rendering    Yes
Reset notification strategy 0x8261
GPU process crash count 0
System visual ID    33
RGBA visual ID  403
Compositor Information
Tile Update Mode    One-copy
Partial Raster  Enabled
GpuMemoryBuffers Status
ATC Software only
ATCIA   Software only
DXT1    Software only
DXT5    Software only
ETC1    Software only
R_8 Software only
R_16    Software only
RG_88   Software only
BGR_565 Software only
RGBA_4444   Software only
RGBX_8888   Software only
RGBA_8888   Software only
BGRX_8888   Software only
BGRX_1010102    Software only
RGBX_1010102    Software only
BGRA_8888   Software only
RGBA_F16    Software only
YVU_420 Software only
YUV_420_BIPLANAR    Software only
UYVY_422    Software only
Display(s) Information
Info    Display[21691195950291266] bounds=[0,0 1200x800], workarea=[0,30 1200x770], scale=2, external.
Color space information {primaries_d50_referred: [[0.6483, 0.3302], [0.3206, 0.5982], [0.1552, 0.0656]], transfer:0.0000*x + 0.0000 if x < 0.0000 else (1.0000*x + 0.0000)**2.2000 + 0.0000, matrix:RGB, range:FULL}
Bits per color component    8
Bits per pixel  24
Video Acceleration Information`

I'd definitely appreciate any further insight. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Hardware Acceleration to avoid using the CPU for video

(check status on chrome://gpu)

- Go to chrome://flags in Chrome
- Find & enable "**Override software rendering list**"
- Restart Chrome
- Check the status again and you will see the green text **Hardware accelerated** on WebGL and Video Decode among others

---

You can go to chrome://media-internals/ and see what's currently playing and there you can see details of the videos playing by chrome

---

**UPDATE**

---

I was reading and found a pretty convincing solution
Youtube uses vp9 and vp8 codec and now only latests GPU can decode vp9. The solution is to force Youtube to use h264

For Chrome you have this extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/h264ify/aleakchihdccplidncghkekgioiakgal/related

For Firefox you have this extension:
https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/h264ify/

> YT probably has not re-encoded all videos to VP9 yet, they used to be VP8. Only newer GPUs can decode VP9 on hardware. For example, GeForce 970 can't, but 1070 can. When GPU can't decode on hardware, the task falls to CPU.

https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/7qafpj/high_cpu_usage_with_youtube/dsnst89

The issue is that with Netflix and other services choosing VP9, you are stuck decoding it through the CPU.

---

**UPDATE 2**

---

- So, to be able to have a browser with hardware acceleration we need Chromium with a VAAPI patch

[https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-beta](https://launchpad.net/%7Esaiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-beta)

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-beta`

`sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

- Then open Chromium and go to `chrome://flags/#enable-accelerated-video`

ENABLE it and restart Chromium

- Now you need to install your VAAPI driver, probably you have it. That you'll have to check for yourself because I really don't know which one you need. For Intel GPU some sites say you need `i965-va-driver`

`sudo apt install i965-va-driver`

You can check the status with `vainfo`

`sudo apt install vainfo`

- Finally install h264ify (link above - For Chrome) to force Youtube to use h264. If you GPU can decode VP9 you don't need this.

---

> === Widevine Support ===
>
> The packages in this PPA have support for Widevine inside Chromium enabled. However, you still need to copy some files from Chrome into Chromium for you to use Netflix (or other websites using Encrypted Media Extensions) in Chromium.
>
> 1. Download and install Chrome (or extract the necessary files, if you know how to do that).
> 2. From the Chrome installation directory (probably /opt/google/chome or something similar), copy libwidevinecdm.so into ~/.config/chromium.
> 3. Restart Chromium.

[https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-beta](https://launchpad.net/%7Esaiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-beta)